# Record webcam video from browser to server without feedback

Tags: javascript, webrtc, recording

1. What is the best way to record video in the browser and upload it to a server (without using flex, flash, wowza, etc.)? I've looked into WebRTC, but it [has not implemented recording](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/) functionality yet, only peer to peer (could my server act as a peer?) So I checked out [whammy](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) and [recordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) but these seem messy (i.e. capturing frames from `canvas`)
2. Also, whenever I enable audio, I get a huge amount of feedback. Is there a way of routing the audio only to the recording without monitoring it (which creates a gigantic feedback loop)

   ```
   var constraints = {
       audio: true, // crazy feedback loop. ouch.
       video: true
   };
   ```

Take a listen:
http://jsfiddle.net/broinjc/7Rb9q/

Answer (score 1):

I've never had an issue with a feedback loop but you may be able to use a TURN server to implement some kind of recording.  That is similar to a server side peer.

Comment: So that jsfiddle doesn't make your speakers scream?

Comment: No I don't think so.  That is a SIP client and a SIP server such as Asterisk would be required.